# How to convert SUMIFS to Array Formula Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have been trying to Convert the SUMIFS formula into Array but its not working in google sheets then i tried to follow online instructions and i am unable to that.

I hope someone can help me to fix the fomrula:

Formula1:

```
SUMIFS('Employee Leave Setup'!$I:$I,'Employee Leave Setup'!$B:$B,$B2:B,'Employee Leave Setup'!$X:$X,K$1)
```

Formula2:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B2:B), iferror(vlookup(B2:B,QUERY({'Employee Leave Setup'!B:X}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col22) Group by Col1 label COUNT(Col22)"",0),2,),0),))")))))
```

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-WRcfbWh6U8Ws3mjgJRiFS7zhjO8yohJ2-dzdnuSjSU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: any sample sheet? hard to fix it without context...

Comment: Updated Sheet link in the description  
player0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(B2:B),COUNTA(K1:W1),LAMBDA(r,c,SUMIFS('Employee Leave Setup'!I:I,'Employee Leave Setup'!B:B,INDEX(B2:B,r),'Employee Leave Setup'!X:X,INDEX(K1:W1,,c))))
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much is it possible to replace `0's` with blank beacuse i cannot use conditional formatting on that sheet rockinfreakshow

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `SUMIF` and concatenate the conditions.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(1/SUMIF('Employee Leave Setup'!B5:B&'Employee Leave Setup'!X5:X,B2:B&K1:W1,'Employee Leave Setup'!I5:I)^-1))
```